# Cypress supports Typescript: what does it really mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I'm being working for a few weeks on a test project with Cypress, and it works great.
Lately, we are evaluating to move to Typescript, and I read Cypress (4.4.0 and later) supports TS.
I was thinking "Great!" but then the lack of documentation is sticking me.
I don't want every time I write something in TS to:

1. make a ts version
2. compile into js
3. be careful of pushing into source code only the TS

When I read Cypress supports TS I thought it would be just a matter of writing and using TS, and Cypress would take of the rest.
Is that simple, and I'm just getting confused, or it is more complicated, and "supports" means something different here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that's what the workflow would be?

Comment: In my mind, I would just write my test (and supporting method and etc) with TS, saving them as TS, and cypress would compile and do what it does today

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when you use the TypeScript preprocessors, I mean why did you think the three steps you've outlined above would be the workflow?

Comment: because, my first "migration" effort was just to create a new test, but this time .ts, and it didn't work. I was expecting Cypress to "understand" the TS, and run it.
I guess I'm missing something

Comment: Yes, that should work. Do you have typescript installed and the tsconfig.json in the cypress directory?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I do

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, then; you'll have to give a [mre]. I was [just able](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit-ts/commit/8745b2491d04c872e9d0e068e574a64161b4fe51) to strip the explicit preprocessor out of a project I maintain, everything worked fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214368/discussion-between-ff8mania-and-jonrsharpe).